# Creating User Interface Elements E.parameter.widgetName

Tags: google-apps-script

---

I'm trying to get parameters through button function `addCallbackElement`. But I get the following error:

> Encountered Error: TypeError: Can not read property "nameRegister" of
>   undefined

```
----------

function **createUserPanel**(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LOGS_SHEET_ID);

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var absolutePanelReg = app.createAbsolutePanel().setId("absolutePanelReg");

  var verticalPanelReg = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("verticalPanelReg");

  var mainPanelReg = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("mainPanelReg");

----------

  var lbNameRegister = app.createLabel().setText("Name of user: ");

  var nameRegister = app.createTextBox().setId("nameRegister").setName("nameRegister");

  var botonSend = app.createButton().setText("Send");

  var handlerRegister = app.createServerHandler("createUser")**.addCallbackElement**(verticalPanelReg);

  botonSend.addClickHandler(handlerRegister);

----------

  verticalPanelReg.add(lbNameRegister);

  verticalPanelReg.add(nameRegister);

  mainPanelReg.add(verticalPanelReg);

  absolutePanelReg.add(mainPanelReg);

  app.add(absolutePanelReg);

  return app;
};


----------

  function **createUser**(e){

    /*var nameRegister ="test";*/

    var nameRegister = e.paramater.nameRegister;

    .......

};
```

Comment: you wrote e.paramater.nameRegister; is it a typo in your question or in your code ? (e.parameter.nameRegister)

Comment: That error appear when i run the script and push the button to get in function "createUser" the parameter e.parameter.nameRegister. So my script dont run and brake becouse it is suppoust that i get null. I think the problem is in addcallback which control the event "e"

Comment: Sorry but you didn't answer my question...did you write **parameter** or **paramater** ?

Comment: TY!! u were right. i Was misspelled paramater >parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved :

paramater > paremeter

Thanks to "Serge insas"